# How to use the verb "filter" to mean include?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, antonyms, academic-writing

Suppose I have a group of items. Each item in the group is of type A,B,C, or D. I want to filter them and keep only items of group A. I can say "I want to filter out B, C, and D from the group", but is there a way to say "I want to filter in items A from the group"? Basically I am looking for an opposite word of *filter out* that means filtering a group to retain items of type X. I found the word sieve but it does not seem to be used for non-physical items. Another word is *identify* but it implies effort required to find item's type given an item.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  In technical writing for certain fields, you could say something like: "select for group A."

Comment: This is a technical writing question, not a question about learning English. The two are in no way the same subject. If you really wanted to know, you could read manuals and see how those authors resolved this question.

Comment: The OP is asking for a specific word, which is on-topic, not how to write technically. I don't expect users to read through an arbitrary number of technical manuals hoping to eventually come across and recognize the usage of the right verb. We're here to help people avoid that kind of drudgery.

Answer (score 2):

## Filter for

In computing, we normally apply filters with the goal of getting a certain set of things, rather than removing others. In computing "filter for" is the common way to refer to this.

From [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2):

> "In Excel, there are several ways to **filter for** unique values..."

This will leave only unique values.

From [Data Science Parichay](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-filter-dataframe-for-multiple-conditions/):

> "In the sample dataframe created, let’s **filter for** all the stocks that are in the Tech industry and have 100 or more shares in the portfolio."

In the resulting output, there are only tech shares with 100 or more shares in the portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the verb **include**.

From the Merriam-Webster website (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/include)

> to take in or comprise as a part of a whole or group

"I only **included** items of type A."

Similarly, the opposite of include is **exclude**.  You could use exclude as an alternative to "filter out."

"This set **includes** items which are A, and **excludes** items which are B, C, or D."

Answer (score 0):

## Extract

Outside of computing, a term very close in meaning is "extract". It doesn't necessarily imply a filter, but if you're physically filtering stones using a filtering grid, trying to get only stones of a certain size, you could say you are *extracting certain stones (with a filter)*.